# SQL query via ssh?

Tags: mysql, ssh

I dont have phpmyadmin on my server. Dont really need it, but I need to run one query, is it possible to do it via SSH? CentOS 6.5

command that I need to run looks like this

```
update wp_wpa_anm set cat = concat(cat,'12,') where scp_egn = 'aut'
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the `mysql` command line client? Whether via SSH as a one-off command execution or actually typing at the prompt, it's the same as it would be locally or via ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
mysql -u username -p database_name -ppassword -e "Select 1"
```

Have a look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-sql-query-directly-on-the-command-line/) for more examples